# Handler control-C signal in java

Tags: java

Besides `addShutdownHook()` and `sun.misc.SignalHandler`, is there any third party library I can use to handle "control-C" signal in Java?

Thanks,

Comment: Why? What's your problem with the existing solutions?

Comment: For addShutdownHook(), it handles all cases if the jvm shut downs. For sun.misc.SignalHandler, it may not be supported for the future release.

Comment: Specifically asking for third-party library recommendations is off-topic for this site. What specifically are you trying to do that you can't do now? What operating systems do you need to support?